# Error coming while generating source code from STM32CubeMx to Keil V5.29

Tags: embedded, iot, stm32, keil, stm32cubemx

**I am making LED blinking program with STM32F103C8T6 i opened the pc13 port for taking Input output**
then this error is occuring while generating code what will i do please help.

**This code is Successfully generated under C:/...... but MDK ARM v5.29 project generation have a problem.**

I have give the right version of  Keil also

[image]

I'm expecting that the code that is generated by STM32CubeMx will open on Keil (MDK ARM). It's opening before but now it's not opening in Keil.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you better describe your problem. What do you mean by "then this code occur"? What do you mean by "project generation have a problem"? Please describe the problem exactly: what do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Provide the error message if any.

Comment: It means when i'm try to generate my code from STM32CubeMx then it shows some error :

"This code is Successfully generated under C:/...... but MDK ARM v5.29 project generation have a problem."

i'm expecting that the code that is generated by STM32CubeMx will open on Keil (MDK ARM). it's opening before but now it's not opening in Keil

Comment: I didn't expect "project generation have a problem" to be part of an error message of a commercial product... Very surprising. There is a known issue regarding the project path. Can you change the *Project Location* such that it is a short path, without any spaces and without any non-English letters, and then try again?

Comment: yes you can see the image description

Comment: Have you Googled the error message text?  Here is one link that Google found, [https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWJBSA3/cubemx-project-generation-have-problem](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWJBSA3/cubemx-project-generation-have-problem)

Comment: i have tried all these methods but no result

Comment: Sadly, CubeMX is not a very reliable tool. For such an easy project, it will be much easier to start from one of the ready-to-use projects provided in STM32Cube. There are several examples that blink a LED.

Comment: Actually this problem arises now earlier it's running fine

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of this error:

1. Creating a project in Cubes, for example, version v5-3-0 or the one that will make the project for Kill without error
2. Run Cubase v5-6-0 and open this project v5-3-0, when compiling, select "modernizations"

Answer (score 0):

Problem **fixed** installation new version **CubeMX V6.3.0** for Windows 10. That **solved** my problem with generating code for Keil.

Also, try some more solutions like reinstalling the **Java** version **older** than **11** or **short** the **path** to the **storage** location in CubeMX folder.

If you want to open an **older project** on a **newer version** of CubeMx, it will have the same problem. so I recommend that for **older versions** of the project done in CubeMX use **V5.2.0.**

Also, pay attention to the Firmware version of the location (*Use Default Firmware Location*) as some older ones may be incompatible with newer **Firmware versions**, which can later cause a programming and runing code problem.

By from A.R. :)